# How do I check auth state in a nextjs page

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next.js

I can't figure out why calling `auth.currentUser` in the case below always returns null. I have another component that listens to the auth state and recognizes that the user is logged in (which is correct).

```
import { auth } from "../lib/firebase";

type Props = {
  hiProp: string;
};

const Index = ({ hiProp }: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => { 
    if (auth.currentUser) { // this never resolves to true
      const router = useRouter();
      router.push("/home");
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>{hiProp}</div>
}

export default Index;

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const hiProp = await getHiProp();

  return {
    props: { hiProp },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) property is documented to be null when it's not certain if there is a user signed in.  When a web page initially loads, it will always be null initially - it does not pre-populate with a user object that was previously signed in.  You have to use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to find out when the user object is first available, as you've said that your other code is doing.

It takes an uncertain amount of time to determine the signed in user.  You can read more about it in this blog post that describes [why currentUser is unexpectedly null](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense considering that I just tested and observed that `auth.currentUser` resolves to true if I wait 2 seconds before executing the `useEffect`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect to happen if the user was actually previously signed in.